# Add vibrating icon with font awesome in calendly script

Tags: font-awesome, calendly

Hi everyone I'm trying to figure out how to add a font awesome icon with a pulse feature inside this script I'm a newbie so I don't really know what I'm doing.
I want to edit before the text that says call or zoom

window.onload = function() { Calendly.initBadgeWidget({ url: 'https://calendly.com/ezrelomd?background_color=fdf8f2&primary_color=56c4c5', text: 'Call or ZOOM', color: '#56c4c5', textColor: '#ffffff', branding: false }); }

Any ideas would be great

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply add the Font Awesome HTML snippet to the text blurb.

Make sure to escape quotes if needed. And of course, check that you've linked Font Awesome's css file.

For example, this snippet works for me (I picked a phone icon with fa-pulse animation):

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<!-- Calendly -->
<link href="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" async></script>
  
<!-- Initialize floating badge with FA icon with some animation -->
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload=function() { Calendly.initBadgeWidget({ url: 'https://calendly.com/ezrelomd?background_color=fdf8f2&primary_color=56c4c5', text: '<i class="fas fa-phone fa-pulse"></i> Call or ZOOM', color: '#56c4c5', textColor: '#ffffff', branding: false }); }</script>
```